# How to display 2 different messages using same trigger in AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I am using Wordpress

Below is my JS:

```
    jQuery("#object").on("keyup change",function(){    
            var object_value = jQuery(this).val();
            jQuery.get(ajaxurl,{'action': 'object','object_value':object_value}, 

     function (msg) { jQuery(".result_object").html(msg);

                       });
      });
```

This is my php:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_object', 'object_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_object', 'object_function');
function object_function(){
  echo 'hello';
  exit();
}
```

Now I want to use the same trigger **keyup change for #object** to display "Welcome" from another function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try encoding php array into JSON and then converting JSON to JS array. Inside PHP you can write if else condition and call two different functions.

```
        $response = array();

        $response['msg_1'] = 'my message 1';
        $response['msg_2'] = 'my message 2';

        echo json_encode($response);
```

In JS,

```
var data = JSON.parse(msg);
alert(data.msg_1);
alert(data.msg_2);
```